# Behaviour on control - when removing the control and adding again, the behaviour is attached again

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, behavior

Working with WPF, MVVM (Caliburn library, ViewModel first)
I have a view that can show 2 things, ChartA and ChartB.

when switching the view from to the other, i'm not creating the view again, but saving it to local member.

When I go from ChartA view to ChartB, than again to ChartA, the behaviour OnAttached is called again. than, the events in the behaviour occure twice!

Why does the behaviour 'created' again, and how can i prevent it.
 i don't want to dispose the view to allow fast navigation between the two.

Code:

in my main window view, i have content control defined (MainWindowView.xaml):

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

in the view model (MainWindowViewModel.cs):

```
public MainWindowViewModel() {

    ...

    // Views
    m_ChartA = new ChartAViewModel(...);
    m_ChartB = new ChartBViewModel(...);

    MainFrame = m_ChartA;

   ...
}
```

my navigation:

```
public void GoToChartBView() {

    ...

    MainFrame = m_ChartB;
}

public void GoToChartAView() {

    ...

    MainFrame = m_ChartA;
}
```

ChartAViewModel and ChartBViewModel has views with behaviour that is re-attached on every navigation.

This is a very simplified code, but that's the idea.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: After some research, it looks like the problem is not a problem with just the behavior, but the whole content control is reloaded again. how can I prevent it?